# Coupled (Solid-Fluid) Heat transfer problem in a Heat Sink

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, elliptic-pde, laplacian, problem-solving

I am trying to solve a coupled heat transfer problem between a solid and fluid (I have under braced the governing equations and labelled them). Eqn. (3) is the partio-integral differential equation I arrive at after coupling both of them. I have added my attempt with an ansatz but this approach gives me trivial solutions.

**Can anyone suggest an alternative way to solve Eqn. (3) *or* point out any shortcoming in the present approach ?**

$\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are constants
$$
\underbrace{\frac{\partial T_f}{\partial x} + \alpha (T_f - T(x,y))=0}_{FLUID} \Rightarrow T_f=e^{-\alpha x}\int e^{\alpha x} T \mathrm{d}x \\ \Rightarrow T_f=\alpha e^{-\alpha x} \Bigg[\int_0^x e^{\alpha s}T(s,y)\mathrm{d}s+\frac{T_{fi}}{\alpha}\Bigg] \tag 1
$$
$T_f(x=0)=T_{fi}$ is a known quantity.
$$
\underbrace{\Bigg(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\Bigg)T-\beta(T-T_f)=0}_{SOLID} \tag 2
$$
Substituting from (1) in (2):
$$
\nabla^2 T - \beta T + \beta\Bigg[\alpha e^{-\alpha x} \Bigg(\int_0^x e^{\alpha s}T(s,y)\mathrm{d}s+\frac{T_{fi}}{\alpha}\Bigg)\Bigg]=0 \tag 3
$$
(3) is dictated by the following boundary conditions:
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \vert_{x=0} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \vert_{x=L} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \vert_{y=d} = 0 , \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \vert_{y=0}=\gamma
$$

**Attempt**
$$
T(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k(y)\cos(\frac{k\pi x}{L})=f_0(y)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(y)\cos(\frac{k\pi x}{L})
$$
The final expression after substituting the ansatz in $(3)$ is:
$$
f'_0(y)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Bigg(f''_k(y)-f_k(y)(\frac{k\pi}{L})^2-\beta f_k(y)\Bigg)\cos(\frac{k\pi x}{L})+\\ \beta e^{-\alpha x}(T_{fi}-f_0(y))+\\ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\alpha L)\beta f_k(y)}{(\alpha L)^2 + (k\pi)^2}\Bigg[(\alpha L) \cos(\frac{k\pi x}{L})-(\alpha L)e^{-\alpha x}+(k\pi)\sin(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\Bigg]=0 \tag 4
$$

Multiplying $(4)$ with $\sin(\tfrac{n\pi x}{L})$ and integrating over the $x$-domain
$$
f'_0(y)\frac{L}{n\pi}(1-\cos(n\pi))+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Bigg[\Bigg(f''_k(y)-f_k(y)(\frac{k\pi}{L})^2-\beta f_k(y)\Bigg)+\frac{(\alpha L)^2\beta f_k(y)}{(\alpha L)^2 + (k\pi)^2}\Bigg]\color{red}{I_1}+\\ \beta(T_{fi}-f_0(y))\frac{L(n\pi)}{(\alpha L)^2 + (n\pi)^2}(1-e^{-\alpha L}\cos(n\pi))+\frac{(n\pi)(\alpha L^2)\beta f_n(y)}{2((\alpha L)^2 + (n\pi)^2)}- \\ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\alpha L)^2\beta f_k(y)}{(\alpha L)^2 + (k\pi)^2}\Bigg(\frac{(n\pi)L}{(\alpha L)^2 + (n\pi)^2}(1-e^{-\alpha L}\cos(n\pi))\Bigg)=0 \tag A
$$

Multiplying $(4)$ with $\cos(\tfrac{n\pi x}{L})$ and integrating over the $x$-domain
$$
\Bigg(f''_k(y)-f_k(y)(\frac{k\pi}{L})^2-\beta f_k(y)\Bigg)\frac{L}{2}+\frac{(\alpha L)\beta f_n(y)}{(\alpha L)^2 + (n\pi)^2}\frac{L}{2}+\\+\beta(T_{fi}-f_0(y))\frac{\alpha L^2 }{(\alpha L)^2 + (n\pi)^2}(1-e^{-\alpha L}\cos(n\pi))+\\ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\alpha L)(k\pi)\beta f_k(y)}{(\alpha L)^2 + (k\pi)^2}\color{blue}{I_2}-\\ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\alpha L)^2 \beta f_k(y)}{(\alpha L)^2 + (k\pi)^2} \Bigg(\frac{\alpha L^2}{(\alpha L)^2 + (n\pi)^2}(1-e^{-\alpha L}\cos(n\pi))\Bigg)=0 \tag B
$$

$$\color{red}{I_1=\int_0^L \cos(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})}$$
$$\color{blue}{I_2=\int_0^L \sin(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})}$$
I want to use $A$ and $B$ to find $f_k(y)$ and $f_0(y)$

---

**Questions**

1. What will be the integral $I_1$ and $I_2$? I know that it amounts to zer0 on the full period $x\in[0,2L]$. When I substitute the integral $\color{red}{I_1}$ in $(A)$ how is the summation going to behave? Can we say something about which terms will vanish and which would remain ?
2. Are $\color{red}{I_1}$ and $\color{blue}{I_2}$ identical under the $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}$ ?

Comment: Can you explain the last point? It seems to me that, at least for each $f_k $ separately, you can satisfy such boundary conditions, no? Is the problem reassembling a $\partial T/\partial y$ constant in $x$ at $y=0$?

Comment: When I try to find $f_k(y)$ in (5) ,it is of the form $f=C_1 e^{\sigma y} +C_2 e^{-\sigma y}$ where $\sigma^2=(\frac{k\pi}{L})^2 + \beta^2$  Things are all right with the $y=d$ condition which gives $C_2=C_1 e^{2d\sigma}$ but when I incorporate the $y=0$ condition ($\gamma$ is a constant), it just falls apart. $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sigma_k C_1 (1-e^{2d\sigma_k})\cos(\frac{k\pi x}{L})=\gamma$. I try to use orthogonality and multiply both sides with $\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ and integrate which just makes the RHS vanish. I hope I have been able to explain the problem clearly

Comment: Ah, ok, so it's indeed reassembling the $y=0$ boundary condition. Now, if I try to work backward, the next thing I worry about is this: (5) and (4) together (I suppose the $n$ in (4) should be a $k$) seem to imply that $T$ obeys the equation $(\nabla^{2} - \beta ) T=0$. This seems rather a whole lot simpler than (3). How does the whole big square bracket in (3) go away?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt You really bring out an insightful point when I think along the way you suggested in your comment and retrace. I have included the intermediate steps, which describes how I reach $(5)$ from $(4)$. A lot of terms just cancel out to leave $(5)$. Have a look at it, Is there something conceptually wrong I am doing here ? Or can there be some workaround to solve (3)?

Comment: Thanks for posting the intermediate steps. The reason I worried about these is this: If it were really true that $T$ obeys $(\nabla^{2} -\beta )T=0$, then it would mean that the solid is not really coupled to the fluid at all! In which case it wouldn't be surprising that you get a trivial solution. So now looking at your intermediate steps, I think the trouble is with your use of orthogonality: The period of your basis functions is $2L$, but you only integrate over $[0,L]$. In particular, in the sentence before (B), the quoted integral is not zero, for example for $n=1$, $k=2$.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt That is a really subtle observation. I really appreciate this. So, If I am understanding correctly, I should adjust my domain as $x\in [0,2L]$ so as to use orthogonality, and modify the final expression accordingly ?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Got it. Your last comment makes the nature of the problem much clearer. I will now read up on getting the integrals done (i.e. look for the non-vanishing terms) and proceed.

Comment: I was rethinking my last comment - maybe there is some trick of extending the domain, I'm not completely excluding it, but it would be surprising. After all, your physical domain really is $[0,L]$, and your basis functions really are only the cosines. And indeed, you need the coupling to the fluid - it doesn't really make sense to try to think up tricks to eliminate those terms by orthogonality.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Hi Michael, I have been trying to solve this problem with some modifications to my approach and have updated the **Attempt** section accordingly. I do still have some doubts in moving florward,. It would be great If you could have a look and clarify some ambiguities which I have summarized in the **Questions** section

Comment: You can easily evaluate $I_1 $ and $I_2 $ using complex exponentials. I don't see that the sums would collapse into anything simple, and this is not surprising - if you just have a $\nabla^{2} $ operator, sines and cosines nicely decouple the equations because they are eigenfunctions. With the additional integral operator, they are not eigenfunctions anymore, so there's no reason for the modes to decouple, as far as I can see. Unless  you have some good reason to believe that this problem can be solved exactly, it probably comes down to numerical solution.

Comment: Numerical solution would be facilitated by using a representation that converges well, so it can be truncated - I don't know whether your sine/cosine representation is like that. As to your second question, since $I_1 $ and $I_2 $ come weighted in different ways under the sums, it's not clear how to relate the respective sums.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Thanks for the input.  Maybe I will try out Laplace transform on $(3)$ if this doesn't works out. I do hope this problem produces an exact solid temperature $T$ distribution which I aim to use to build expressions for thermal resistance of miniaturized heat sinks ($(3)$). The $\nabla^2$ operator actually describes conduction in the solid in two directions, one perpendicular to flow (which we want) and the other parallel to flow (which is a deteriorating effect and is commonly known as axial conduction). The boundary condition at $y=0$ is a heat flux which models

Comment: the heat generation from the device on top of which the sink is placed.